# Javascript Typeout Text Issues

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm staff on a gaming forum, thus I'm permitted to use a custom html title on my profile and posts. I've been playing around with this and have a few issues.

### Issue #1: Multiple Instances - Visibility

If I have multiple posts on a single page, that each show the title, the title will only appear in the top post. The rest will be blank.

### Issue #2: Multiple Instances - Speed

If I have multple posts on a single page, that each show the title, based on how many instances there are, it will multiply the delay speed of typing and going to the next set of text.

I'd be very grateful if anyone could point out the issues they see, *I'm fairly new to Javascript.*

```
        /* Typeout Text Array */
    var items = ["NGU Content Manager", "GTA V Modder", "Progressing Programmer", "Need help? PM me!"];
    /* Variable Shit */
    var text; arrcount = 0; var delay = 75; var arraydelay = 3000; var cur = 1; var cursor = "_"; var prefix = "> ";
    /* Typeout Functions */
    function sim() {
        var elem = document.getElementById("kryptus");
        elem.value = prefix + text.substr(0, cur) + cursor;
        cur++
        if (cur > text.length) {
            cur = 1;
            setTimeout("nextarr()", arraydelay);
        }
        else {
            setTimeout("sim()", delay);
        }
        cursorchange();
    }
    function cursorchange() {
        if (cur == text.length) {
          cursor = "";
        } else {
          cursor = "_";
        }
    }
    function nextarr() {
        if (arrcount >= items.length) {
            arrcount = 0;
        } 
        text = items[arrcount];
        sim();
        arrcount++;
    }
    /* Typeout */
    var myurl = "http://www.nextgenupdate.com/forums/members/1158931-kryptus.html";
    var currenturl = window.location;
    var centertext = "";
      if (POSTBIT_LEGACY && THIS_SCRIPT == 'showthread') {
          prefix = "";
          centertext = "text-align:center;";
        }
    document.write('<input id="kryptus" readonly="readonly" style="width: 100%; border: none; color: black; background-color: transparent; font-weight: bold; ' + centertext + '"></input>');
    if (cur == 1) {
      nextarr();
    } else {
      setTimeout("nextarr()", arraydelay);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well are you creating multiple elements with the `"kryptus"` id? That is invalid html, and `document.getElementById("kryptus")` will only find the first one.

Comment: @nnnnnn Like I said, I'm fairly new to all of this. As far as I know it's only creating 1, how would I create multiple?

Comment: Your question was about multiple posts on a single forum page, so I thought you meant that the code you've shown is repeated once per post.

Comment: @nnnnnn Post #1 on page: http://prntscr.com/76lgh8 Post #1 Elements: http://prntscr.com/76lh13
Post #2 on page: http://prntscr.com/76lgod Post #2 Elements: http://prntscr.com/76lhet

And when there's multiple posts, depending on how many there are, it'll speed up the first one.